# Cannot destructure arrays with re-assigned variables in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I kind of like the array destructuring in ES6.

I have a test case where I query the buttons and want to directly pull out the button variables rather than mess around with arrays, like so:

```
let [backButton, forwardButton]: HTMLElement[] = await screen.findAllByRole('button')
fireEvent.click(forwardButton);
```

However I want to repeat the destructuring later in the code, like so:

```
let [backButton, forwardButton]: HTMLElement[] = await screen.findAllByRole('button')
fireEvent.click(forwardButton);

//do some stuff

[backButton, forwardButton]: HTMLElement[] = await screen.findAllByRole('button')
fireEvent.click(backButton);
```

Unfortunately Typescript does not seem to allow me to do this.

I get an error

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ new (): HTMLElement; prototype: HTMLElement; }'.
```

Is there any way of being able to destructure twice in one block?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the sole problem (since i don't see how it connects to the error message), but the second destructuring should not have a type. Ie, it should be `[backButton, forwardButton] = await screen.findAllByRole('button')`

Comment: perfect! That answers my question .............!

Comment: please post this as an "answer"

Comment: You can always post an answer yourself since you were able to resolve the problem. You could also delete the question but since it's not quite a simple "typo", it might be worth keeping for future readers.

Comment: yeah i know.... but i wanted to reward the guy the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTMLElement[]` type definition is only needed when the variables are first created. When you try to do it again on the second line, you are confusing typescript. So the fix is to remove the type from the second destructuring:

```
[backButton, forwardButton] = await screen.findAllByRole('button')
```